# Product Sigma Algebra, Explicitly

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2)$ be measurable spaces and define the product sigma algebra on $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$ as
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 = \sigma(\{A_1 \times A_2: A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2\}).
$$

I'm trying to give myself an example of a product sigma algebra - is the following correct?  In particular, the pairs involving the empty set and whole space seem awkward.

Let $\Omega_1 = \{1,2\}$ and $\Omega_2 = \{3,4\}$. Let $\mathcal{F}_1 = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \Omega_1 \}$ and $\mathcal{F}_2 = \{\emptyset, \{3\}, \{4\}, \Omega_2 \}$.  Then
$$
\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 = \{(1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4)\}
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 = \sigma(\{\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}, \{(\emptyset, 3)\}, \{(\emptyset, 4)\}, \{(\emptyset, \Omega_2)\}, \{(1, \emptyset)\}, \{(1, 3)\},  \{(1, 4)\},  \{(1, \Omega_2)\}, \{(2, \emptyset)\}, \{(2, 3)\},  \{(2, 4)\},  \{(2, \Omega_2)\}, \{(\Omega_1, \emptyset)\}, \{(\Omega_1, 3)\},  \{(\Omega_1, 4)\},  \{(\Omega_1, \Omega_2)\}\}). 
$$

I'm not sure this is right though. In particular, I'm not sure that $(\emptyset, 1) \in \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal F_1\otimes\mathcal F_2=2^{\Omega_1}\otimes2^{\Omega_2}=2^{\Omega_1\times\Omega_2}$. (Not the most exciting example of sigma-algebras, but still...)